# ImageButton first click / second click?

Tags: android, imagebutton, dynamically-generated

I have an `ImageButton` with the image resource `R.drawable.img1` and I want to change the image from `R.drawable.img1` to `R.drawable.img2` or from `R.drawable.img2` to `R.drawable.img1` everytime I click on the `ImageButton`.

I was trying this way but it doesn't work:

```
Integer img1 = (Integer) gridlayout.getChildAt(index).getTag(R.drawable.img1);
Integer img2 = (Integer) gridlayout.getChildAt(index).getTag(R.drawable.img2);

if(img1 == R.drawable.img1){
    //code...
}else if(img2 == R.drawable.img2){
    //code...
}
```

I set `ImageButton`'s dynamically with this code:

```
ImageButton imgBtn1 = new ImageButton(this);

imgBtn1.setId(id);
imgBtn1.setImageResource(R.drawable.img1);
imgBtn1.setTag(R.drawable.ing1);
imgBtn1.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
imgBtn1.setPadding(5,5,5,5);

GridLayout.LayoutParams params = new GridLayout.LayoutParams();
params.setMargins(-7,-7,-7,-7);
params.width = fieldSize;
params.height = fieldSize;

gridlayout.addView(imgBtn1, index, params);
```

Thanks!

Comment: Y dont you maintain a boolean value false = image1; true image2. Change everytime button onClick is triggered.

Comment: I am using grid of ImageButtons, so it will be to much complicated this way.

Answer (score 0):

I am just giving one of the several solutions available ,what i would is in the `onCreate` i would load the imagebutton with one of images available ,then i would create a class variable i and would set it to 1, when ever i click the imagebutton ,on the `onClick` of it ,i would increment i and do this 
    if(i%2==0)
{
setImage1;}
else
{set image2;}

Answer (score 0):

So, if you want to display a different button each time, I would create two buttons in the layout, hide one and show one. When the visible one is clicked, hide it and show the second button. I think that will be easier. You can alternatively use a local class variable to keep count of clicks and switch buttons accordingly.

Comment: Lets say I want to check what resource is on this button. Cos this way will be to slow if I am using multiple buttons (grid 10x10 for example).

Comment: You can assign the button an id that you can use to see which button was clicked.

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean showingFirst = true;
if (showingFirst) {
    //code here for set needed image on first click
    showingFirst = false;
} else {
    //code here for set needed image on Second click
    showingFirst = true;
}
```